# gulp uncss is filtering selectors needed by my javascript

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

As expected, when I run gulp uncss on my index.html file, it removes all the css rules from my stylesheet not used in the html.  Problem is my app is primarily javascript so much of the content isn't rendered until the js executes in the browser.  Does anybody know of a good way to execute the index.html file in a server via gulp and capture the html string (post javascript execution) so that I can pass it to uncss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options...

**Option 1**

Use the [`timeout` parameter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss#timeout) to set a delay when loading the HTML page, giving the JS time to load.

**Option 2**

If you have control over the JS-injected content you could prefix classnames, ids and other attributes with a string (something like `js-`) to make it easy to ignore those using the [`ignore` parameter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss#ignore).

**Option 3**

Go manual - the only thing that worked for me (using Zurb Foundation) was to use Chrome's Dev Tools to look for JS-injected content. Thankfully I only had to add a few classes.